# Swift 3 `+` operator bug when using Array type

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, operators, swift3

In the below example, I'm trying to make it so people can freely use the `+` operator to make an array of `Request` instances.

```
struct Request {}

typealias BatchRequest = Array<Request>

func +(lhs: Request, rhs: Request) -> BatchRequest {
    return [lhs, rhs]
}

func +(lhs: Request, rhs: BatchRequest) -> BatchRequest {
    var arr: [Request] = [lhs]
    arr.append(contentsOf: rhs)
    return arr
}

func +(lhs: BatchRequest, rhs: Request) -> BatchRequest {
    var arr: [Request] = lhs
    arr.append(rhs)
    return arr
}

func +(lhs: BatchRequest, rhs: BatchRequest) -> BatchRequest {
    var lhs: [Request] = lhs
    lhs.append(contentsOf: rhs)
    return lhs
}

let req1 = Request()
let req2 = Request()
let req3 = Request()

print(req1 + req2)
// Prints "[Request(), Request()]"

print(req1 + req2 + req3)
// Error: argument type 'BatchRequest' (aka 'Array<Request>') does not conform to expected type 'Any'
```

When used with two operands, this works fine, but when using with three or more, it doesn't work.

Changing the operator to `&` or using a custom operator with left associativity works fine, so I can only guess there's something about the `AdditionPrecedence` group that makes the overloading throw an error. (Hopefully it's not a bug in Swift)

Although I could settle for `&`, I would like to know if there is some way to override the behavior of `+` only for certain types or actually redeclare existing operators.

(I don't have too much hope though. Nothing in the documents suggest that I can..)

Comment: It does indeed seem as if the Swift compiler have difficulty making use of the _left_ associativity of the `+` operator (or specifically, the `AdditionPrecendence` prec. group) to infer the types of the three-operands example. As a way to test out this hypothesis, we can note that we may explicitly seperate what is to be considered `rhs` and `lhs` successfully, `print((+)(req1 + req2, req3))`. This could imply a bug, especially as we don't run into the same issue when using a custom operator. Note also that we run into the same issue if `BatchArray` is a tuple, so not related to `arr.append`.

Comment: @dfri I think it's a bug. In Swift 2.2, the same code works fine.

Comment: Indeed. I believe [the following existing bug report (SR-1668)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1668) covers the same issue (more than two operands used in an expression where on of the operators are a custom overload of existing operators).

Answer (score 0):

Tried it in Xcode 7.3.1 (Swift 2.2), and the above code worked fine.

I did remember writing this code in Swift 2.2 and verifying that the code worked fine, but then I wasn't sure.

I'm going to file a bug report to Swift.

[image: Xcode 7.3.1]